# Where can I look up purchase/activation date for Apple products?

Tags: warranty, hardware

I can't remember exactly when it was I bought my iPhone.  I thought that perhaps I could look it up via Apple somehow.

I'm aware of the [Check Your Service and Support Coverage](https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do) page, but that's not presenting me with the activation date—only the status of my warranty and such.

Comment: Same here: I get a statement that it's been greater than a year when checking a desktop Mac, but no details.